# Ухудшение качества картинки при открытии через браузер

Tags: файлы, изображения, браузер, конвертация

Первый раз столкнулся с проблемой. Есть картинка: https://testim24.ru/upload/7a578d569c12b6c15a0fc979a26aa672.jpg И если открывать через браузер - она какая-то засвеченная. НО! скачиваю с сервера, открываю - нормальная. Так же когда телеграм/вайбер подтягивает ее по ссылке - все хорошо. Возможно повлияло то что принял через вайбер бота, изначально она была в png а стала jpg. Подскажите в чем причина и как исправить

Answer (score 1):

Я решил сам скачать и открыть этот файл. Но у меня не получилось это сделать, а программа выдал надпись "Not a JPEG file: starts with 0x89 0x50".

Через некоторое время я [нашел ответ на stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11310220/why-am-i-getting-the-error-not-a-jpeg-file-starts-with-0x89-0x50):

> "0x89 0x50" - это начало PNG файла. То есть эта картинка имеет расширение PNG, но сохранена с расширением JPG.